# Fragment class has a Async Task method, how can i call this Async Task method from the TabHost parent class

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am developing an application which contain 3 tabs in the home page.

First Tab(Fragment class) has Async task method , and i have a action bar in the parent class(Tab Host Parent class) when i am clicking that action v=bar menu item i want to call that Async Task method how can i call this method

I am calling like this its getting error

((new First_Fragment())).new Load_Task.execute();

the error is like this

```
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716): Process: com.example.com, PID: 9716
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:143)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.example.com$Load_Task.onPreExecute(Bol_Contacts_Screen.java:396)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.example.com.Fragment_Class.onOptionsItemSelected(Fragment_Class.java:256)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2617)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1012)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:741)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:884)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:177)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1129)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2927)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3676)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
04-10 19:35:48.768: E/AndroidRuntime(9716):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: You can access it with your parent activity or make a static method to call your `AsyncTask`.

Comment: i am already try this kind of code, but its not invoking the getActivty in the Async static method..@Piyush Gupta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have used something like this in your parent activity where you wanted to replace the container with the specific child fragment:

```
Fragment fragmentChild = new FragmentChild();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container, fragmentChild, "fragChild" ).commit();
```

Now you just have to code something like this where you want to call child class method:

```
Fragment fragment (FragmentChild)   
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragChild");
fragment.<your_async_method>();
```

Comment: you can upvote if it is the right solution :) @Nani536

Comment: i don't have sufficient reputations for up vote...when ever i am getting reputations to up vote i will vote...@Najeebullah Shah